# uninitialized local variable error even thought I initialized it (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to programming and not sure what I did wrong but I'm getting the error on `line 20`, it says that I haven't initialized `intownMiles` and `highwayMiles`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double intownMPG = 23.5;
    double highwayMPG = 28.9;
    double intownMiles;
    double highwayMiles;
    double gallons = intownMiles / intownMPG + highwayMiles / highwayMPG;

    cout << "Please enter the number of in-town driving miles:  " << endl;
    cin >> intownMiles;
    cout << "Please enter the number of highway driving miles:  " << endl;
    cin >> highwayMiles;
    cout << "The total number of gallons required is: " << gallons  << "gal" << endl;

}
```

Comment: Well, you indeed  haven't initialized `intownMiles` and `highwayMiles`... You have only declared them without giving any initial values (and compiler won't do it for you). Note that `cin >> intownMiles;` will be executed *after* the value of `gallons` is calculated.

Comment: I think you may have a very basic  misunderstanding of how a C++ program works - the statements are executed sequentially.

Comment: "`using namespace std;`" - bad habit. It *will* bite you when your code gets large. Just don't.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
double intownMiles;
double highwayMiles;
double gallons = intownMiles / intownMPG + highwayMiles / highwayMPG;
```

You *clearly* have *not* initialized those variables before using them. All you did was *define* them - so they exist, but have *indeterminate* values until you assign to them (which you never do).

Initialize the variables to sane initial values when you define them and the compiler warning will go away (and your code will no longer have Undefined Behaviour).

Comment: `intownMiles` and `highwayMiles` are **defined**, not just **declared**.

Answer (score 1):

Writing C++ is different from writing regular math equations.

Firstly, **the code is executed sequentially**.

When execution reaches this line:

```
double gallons = intownMiles / intownMPG + highwayMiles / highwayMPG;
```

The value of `gallons` is computed *immediately*, using the *current values* of variables used in the expression.

You haven't assigned any values to some of the variables prior to using them, so you can't expect to get a meaningful result.

When you change those variables later, the value of `gallons` is not affected.
So you have to ask the user for values of those variables *first*, and *then* compute the formula.